# Text overflow hides text when it shouldn't in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I want to have various tags in a container and have them display ellipsis when the tag text is too big (i.e. when it would stretch beyond the width of the container). The problem I am facing is that in Safari, the ellipsis are displayed even though the tag has space to display the full content.

This is the code that shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```css
.tag {
  height: 30px;
  background: #F67;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.content {
  float: left;
  max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.icon {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tag">
    <span class="content">Some tag</span>
    <a href="#" class="icon">X</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tag">
    <span class="content">Some tag</span>
    <a href="#" class="icon">X</a>
  </div>
  <span class="tag">
        blahbsalkfnewijfnewifbwiefnbijfneifjnweifniwjenfewi
      </span>
  <div class="tag">
    <span class="content">Some tags</span>
    <a href="#" class="icon">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're running the snippet above in Safari(v8.0.8 is the one I am using) you can see the last tag shows ellipsis even though it still has space to stretch and display the full text. If you can't see what I am talking about here is a screenshot of the issue:
[text-overflow problem on safari image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsn6n.png)

Small mention about the 'X' is that it is intended as an icon someone could click on and delete the tag, but that functionality is not the subject of this question.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using this trick: adding a non-break space right after the text. You can add it directly into your html, like `<div class="ellipsis">Test&nbsp;</div>` or you can use the `:after` pseudo element. Here's the `.ellipsis` class that I'm using:

```css
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis:after {
  content: "\0000a0";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}
```

The use of `:after` has another advantage, it's hidden by setting `width: 0;`, so you won't notice a larger gap between this element and the thing next to it (another element or a border).

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Love the :after idea. (Can be easily removed later without disrupting page flow.) Thank you!!

Comment: I had to set `width: 1px` to make this work for my site.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the following lines from your `.content` element it works fine by me.

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

example: http://codepen.io/WartClaes/pen/ZQxaKW?editors=1100

Edit: although when looking further I see that you don't always use the same HTML structure? Which results in the double text overflow declaration. Isn't it possible to always use the same structure?

Comment: Do you mean leave them only on the `tag` class and remove them from the `content`? If yes, then that will break if I have a tag longer than one line; the text will stretch under the `icon`. 

Regarding the HTML structure, the tags are meant to be used either as editable or not editable. Hence the structure; but I'm not set on that so can easily change if a fix for the Safari issue is found.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a class when you have the icon? That way you could just change the width of the `.content` to avoid the overflowing in that particular case. I think that that way it will be easier to maintain?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. Presume that there are only editable tags, so content and icon inside a wrapper. If in the snippet I linked I use the text `Some tag` it fits, if I use `Some tags` it doesn't fit anymore. Hopefully you can also see this behaviour.

Comment: I updated my preview: http://codepen.io/WartClaes/pen/ZQxaKW?editors=1100. Is this something you want to reach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "width" for the text, down to the text-overflow:

width: 100%; /*Or the size you need*/

It works for me in the safari 13.

Answer (score 0):

```css
letter-spacing: -1px;
```

This solves my problem, but other browsers just look crowded

Answer (score 0):

`width: min-content;`

Don't ask me why it works, but it works. Safari 11 on iOS and up.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content#browser_compatibility

Edit: This doesn't always work, depending on the layout. When it doesn't, use a specific width on the parent element, e.g. width: 100%.